# Can't update information in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ms-access, datagridview

[image: Screenshot]

This is datagrid view, which is connected to access data base.
There is a column called "Status" (you can see it in red square).
I would like to update the text in it (Arrival) to text (In House) by pressing the "Check in button" ***in selected row***. How can i do this?
Thanks in advance.

```
 private void searchbd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages["tabPage1"])
            {
                try
                {

                    string dtparrival = this.dateTimePicker4.Text.ToString();
                    string statusarrival = "Arrival";

                    string strSql = "SELECT * FROM guestreg WHERE g_status = '" + statusarrival + "' AND g_ad = '" + dtparrival + "'";


                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable scores = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(scores);
                    arrivaldgv.DataSource = scores;
                    /**************************************************************************/
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_totalrate"].Visible = false;
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["u_added"].Visible = false;
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["u_timeadded"].Visible = false;
                    /**************************************************************************/
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_name"].HeaderText = "Name";  //1
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_surname"].HeaderText = "Surname"; //2
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_company"].HeaderText = "Company"; //3
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_ad"].HeaderText = "Arrival Day"; //4
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_dd"].HeaderText = "Departure Day"; //5
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_amountofdays"].HeaderText = "Amount of Days"; //6
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_na"].HeaderText = "Number of Adults"; //7
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_amountofdays"].HeaderText = "Amount of Days"; //8
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_room"].HeaderText = "Room Number"; //9
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_rate"].HeaderText = "Rate"; //10
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_totalrate"].HeaderText = "Total Rate"; //11
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_info"].HeaderText = "Information"; //12
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["u_added"].HeaderText = "User"; //13
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["u_timeadded"].HeaderText = "Time"; //14
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_status"].HeaderText = "Status"; //15
                    /**************************************************************************/
                    connection.Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please, try again.");
                }
```

Comment: Let's see some code.  What have you tried?  What does your data model/classes look like?

Comment: @Kyle, i have updated the question and added the code of "search" button

Comment: Which part is causing you a problem? The "check in" button click? Getting the selected row? Updating the text? Or saving the value back to your Access database?

Comment: @Kyle, just don't have an idea how to change the value of selected row by pressing the button "Check in". The value should be changed to "In House"

Comment: @stuartd, the problem is - i can't understand how to make the value of the column "STATUS" change by pressing the "Check in button". It should change from "Arrival" to "In House"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you only want to update value in dataGridView cell, not value in database table.

The simplest way is:

```
    private void CheckInButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        int col = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

        dataGridView1[col, row].Value = "In House";
    }
```

You can add some validation of course. For example: Check if any cell is selected.

Comment: Hello Jakub Nowacki, no, i would like to change it also in data base

Comment: So I think, you can try to use SqlCommandBuilder, which should generate an update command for you. 

Take a look at some instructions here:
http://csharp.net-informations.com/dataadapter/commandbuilder-sqlserver.htm

Comment: thank you! Will check it in an hour and will tell you the result.